# Need help handling IllegalArgumentException in reactivemongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

The below code tries to get document by ID using Reactivemongo. However, I don't know how to deal with the IllegalArgumentException thrown when the ID is wrong!
Tried the below code but the compiler is not happy with `case _ => Future.successful(None)`, it says: `found scala.concurrent.Future[None.type] required Option[SomeModel]` . Also tried `case _ => None` with no success.

```
def getById(id: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[SomeModel]]={
    this.get( BSONDocument("_id" ->  BSONObjectID(id)) ).map {
      res => Future.successful(res)
    }.recover {
      case _ => Future.successful(None)
    }
  }

def get(query: BSONDocument)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[SomeModel]]= {
    collection.find(query).one[SomeModel](ReadPreference.Primary)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing [`recover`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U%3E:T]%28pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U]%29%28implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[U]) and [`recoverWith`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recoverWith[U%3E:T]%28pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,scala.concurrent.Future[U]]%29%28implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[U]).

Both functions expect a `PartialFunction` which accept a `Throwable` and both functions return a `Future[U]`, but

- `recover`'s `PartialFunction` should return a `U`
- while `recoverWith`'s should return a `Future[U]`.

In your case, you can use `recover` :

```
get(BSONDocument("_id" ->  BSONObjectID(id)))
  .recover { case _ => None }
  // you don't need map(res => Future.successful(res)
```

---

Update: You could edit `get` to return a failed `Future` instead of throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`. A possible way would be to use `Try` and its `recover` :

```
import scala.util.Try

def get(query: BSONDocument)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[SomeModel]] = 
  Try(collection.find(query).one[SomeModel](ReadPreference.Primary))
    .recover{ case t => Future.failed(t) }.get
```

---

Update:

It worked when I did

```
def getById(id: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[SomeModel]]={
      Try(this.get(BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONObjectID(id)))).recover{ case t => Future.failed(t) }.get
  }

def get(query: BSONDocument)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[SomeModel]]={
      collection.find(query).one[SomeModel](ReadPreference.Primary)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, compiler feels better now. But I'm not able to catch the exception. Say `val resultFuture = get(BSONDocument("_id" ->  BSONObjectID(id)))
  .recover { case _ => None }` neither resultFuture.onFailure nor resultFuture.onSuccess is reached/matched. How can I match the recover `case _ => None` pattern?

Comment: Does `collection.find` throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or return a failed `Future` ?

Comment: Still throws `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: I have updated my answer to let `get` return a failed `Future` instead of throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Used your code but the exception is still thrown unhandled! What do you think?

Comment: Updated your answer with what worked! Very strange! Why that worked and yours didn't? I prefer to have it at the `get` level rather than `getById` level. Any idea?

Comment: I think the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when you create a `BSONDocument` with an invalid ID.

Comment: Oh! How I missed this :D . You are right. I simulated a mongoDB ID that doesn't exist by using a valid one and deleting one character. Seems it expects an ID with a certain length. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question,

> ...I don't know how to deal with the IllegalArgumentException thrown when the ID is wrong!

I think, the better solution is

```
def getById(id: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[SomeModel]]={

    //Try to parse bson id from string. This method return Try[BSONObjectId] and we can simple `match` them
    BSONObjectId.parse(id) match {

       // valid bson id 
      case Success(bsonId) => this.get( BSONDocument("_id" -> bsonId) )

      //We catch IllegalArgumentException and just return None
      case Failure(ex) => Future[Option[SomeModel]](None)
    }
}
```

In your code, Scala try to parse BSONObjectId from string before call `get` method, and if string id is invalid BSON throwing exception in current thread (not in the `Future` result of method `get`). That's why  `recover {case _ => Future.successful(None)}` will not execute. Methods `recover` and `recoverWith` executes only if `Future` store some exception. For example, this code will work too:

```
def getById(id: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[SomeModel]]={

    //create Future, that will be store exception (if id is invalid) or valid BSON id.
    //method flatMap because this.get return Future type.
    Future(BSONObjectId(id)).flatMap{ bsonId =>  

        //this executes only if string id is valid bson.
        this.get( BSONDocument("_id" ->  bsonId) )
    }.recover{

        //this will be execute only if string id is invalid bson. 
        // the best practice to catch non-fatal Throwables via class scala.util.control.NonFatal 
        case NonFatal(e) =>  None
    }
}
```

But this variant is complicated (create one more `Future`, `flatMap` them, recover with `NonFatal` control). I would prefer the first variant with `parse` method (it's mush more easy without some extra futures and controls).